# Why does git set filemode 755 for files that should be 750?

Tags: git, permissions, chmod

In my local repository I have a file whose filemode is 550. In .git/config, filemode=true is set on both my local repo and on the server's repo. But when I pull from github, the file always comes down as 775!

I'm very confounded by this. Is there a way to tell git how to do the perms for files? So it doesn't change them like this? I'm also curious, why was git designed like this, to not respect file perms? I realize I can just make a shell script to fix it afterwards, etc., but I'm just curious.

Sorry if this was a duplicate, I couldn't find anything that addressed this exactly.

Answer (score 7):

Git stores only one single bit for file permissions: execute, or no-execute.

The remaining bits are set based on your umask (on Unix/Linux-alike systems at least).  If you want 640 or 750 settings, set your umask to `027` instead of `022`.  (All the shells have `umask` as a built in command, for the same reason that all shells have `chdir` as a built-in.)  Remember that the umask setting is "bits to take away", so `027` means "take away group write; take away other read+write+execute".

(The umask is why most programs should mostly create most files with mode `0666` or `0777`.)

Comment: Here's [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34546706/4410590) from another question that references [Git index format](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt)