# Why GIT does not detect the difference between the file mode 644 and 664?

Tags: git

Why GIT does not detect the difference between the file mode 644 and 664, but 755 it detects:

```
$:~/docker/images/php_cron/config$ ls -l crontab 
-rw-r--r--  1 saf  staff  4663 31 Dez 09:38 crontab

$:~/docker/images/php_cron/config$ chmod 664 crontab 
$:~/docker/images/php_cron/config$ ls -l crontab 
-rw-rw-r--  1 saf  staff  4663 31 Dez 09:38 crontab

$:~/docker/images/php_cron/config$ git status
On branch komplett-modularisiert
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/komplett-modularisiert'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
$:~/docker/images/php_cron/config$ chmod 755 crontab 

$:~/docker/images/php_cron/config$ git status
On branch komplett-modularisiert
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/komplett-modularisiert'.



Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   crontab

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I would like that GIT detects any kind of file mode changes. I got issues when I deployed by git pulling my files on a server on which they had different file modes than in my repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had met this problem before, and there is no solution for it.
The only way is to save the permissions when push the code to server. And restore the permission to the files when pull the code from server.
I had written one script to do this work, you can refer to the url: [sr-perm](https://github.com/bobicui/sr-perm)

Answer (score 11):

The only file mode Git tracks is in an "executable" bit. Since neither `0644` nor `0664` means the file is executable in any way, Git will not ever see it as a change.

From [Git index format](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt):

> ```
>   32-bit mode, split into (high to low bits)
>
>     4-bit object type
>       valid values in binary are 1000 (regular file), 1010 (symbolic link)
>       and 1110 (gitlink)
>
>     3-bit unused
>
>     9-bit unix permission. Only 0755 and 0644 are valid for regular files.
>     Symbolic links and gitlinks have value 0 in this field.
> ```

The important part is the "Only 0755 and 0644 are valid for regular files.". All other file permissions are reinterpreted as `0755` or as `0644`, depending on whether the `0100` bit (`u+x`) is set: from [cache.h](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/cache.h):

> ```
> #define ce_permissions(mode) (((mode) & 0100) ? 0755 : 0644)
> ```

This macro is used to map OS-level file permissions to Git file permissions.

If you need to track file permissions in your repository, you'll have to find a different way of doing it. One thing you could try is store a script in your repository that resets all file permissions to whatever values you specify. You can automate the creation of the script before committing (not with Git itself, but using any other language or tool you like), and you can execute the script after pulling.

Comment: But why isn't `chmod 654` (starting from `644`) detected?

Comment: @Marth I'll try to find a reference, but from a quick test, it only appears to look at the `0100` bit: if that is set, it treats the file as executable.

Comment: @Marth: Because `chmod 654` doesn't allow the owner to execute the file. And `git` checks only the permissions of the current user, as does bash and the fs in general. Try it, create a script with `echo hi` and set it to `0654`. You're not allowed to run it due to owners access being `6`. Change the owner to some other user, and you're now allowed, since group access is `5`. You're not allowed to change it anymore, though.

Comment: In case you wonder what a "gitlink" is: It is used internally by `git submodule`, see [its man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for details.

Comment: @Marth, Git does not track file's permissions bits (and owning user and group, too) -- only the executable bit. I beleive this is explained in the official Git FAQ, and the reasoning is that *Git is not a deployment tool* and it's not a file archiver either. Also consider what happens on Windows with possibly very complex ACLs set on a file or on a POSIX system with POSIX ACLs set on a file. This problem does not have a general solution, so if you need to preserve metadata on your files you have to invent a way to do that.

Comment: @Marth, the exact details of how to do that may vary. Say, a pre-commit hook could traverse your index, and for each entry located there try to read the permissions bits the matching file/directory has in the work tree, write this information to a separate file and update a special index entry (say, ".permissions") with this data. Or you could just commit a shell script which is to be executed on the work tree after the checkout.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the flag to tell git to track mode changes

```
git config core.fileMode true // or false
```

From [git-config(1)](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10.1/git-config.html):

> ```
> core.fileMode
>       If false, the executable bit differences between the index and the
>       working copy are ignored; useful on broken filesystems like FAT.
>       See git-update-index(1). 
>
>     True by default.
> ```

---

#### [umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)

If its still not tracking your changes use this:

```
umask 022
```

It will *"fix"* this issue for you.

`umask 002` will set new created files with group-writable permissions.

You can add it to your `~/.profile` to set it as the default git beahavior

```
git(){(umask 0022; command git "$@")}
```

Comment: I have already set it to true. It does not detect file modes between 644 and 664.

Comment: *"If false, the executable bit differences"*. OP is asking about the write bit.

Comment: This is why you have to set the `umask` as well

Comment: No, this variable is on by default for posix systems.  This variable exists to tell git that its operating on a windows system that lacks the executable bit and it should therefore not try to commit a bunch of mode changes just because the platform doesn't support them.